# Seeking open source web client alternative to Geocortex Essentials?

Tags: open-source-gis, software-recommendations

What is best the opensource webclient alternative To Geocortex essentials? 
For someone  without much coding experience.

Comment: Will you manage the server? IMHO, setting up the server and managing it is the tedious bit. I wild ass guess that setting up the server for Goecortex is not trivial either.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the server setup and management issues, I recommend QGIS Webserver, as it gives WYSIWYG of the desktop project being reproduced on the web.